# Why scenePhase value is .background while the app is in the foreground?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I want to do something from the model file when the app goes to the background, like stop the timer or something else. But when I run the app and check for the `scenePhase` value it returns `.background` while the app is in the foreground.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Model {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    var timerSubscription: AnyCancellable?
    init() {
        timerSubscription = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect().sink { _ in
            if self.scenePhase == .background {
                // do something when the app goes to the background.
            }
            print(self.scenePhase) // print background while the app is in the foreground.
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            
    }
}
```

Comment: @Environment must be in view

Comment: @Asperi why? is there a documentation page that says this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carefully read first sentence to the end:

[image]

Update:

> what do you suggest to achieve the logic I described in the model file?

Move environment to view, where it should be, and inject it back into model when view have it or detect change on it, like

```
class Model {
    var scenePhase: ScenePhase?
    var timerSubscription: AnyCancellable?
    init() {
        timerSubscription = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect().sink { _ in
            if self.scenePhase == .background {
                // do something when the app goes to the background.
            }
            print(self.scenePhase ?? .none) // print background while the app is in the foreground.
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase  // << here !!
    var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) {
               self.model.scenePhase = $0  // << update !!
            }
            .onAppear {
               self.model.scenePhase = scenePhase  // << initial !!
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it, what do you suggest to achieve the logic I described in the model file?